# Cosmos DB Stored Proc returning No Results

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I've been reading the limited documentation and from what I've seen, this query should work.

```
// SAMPLE STORED PROCEDURE
function sample() {
var prefix = "";
var collection = getContext().getCollection();
var data = collection.readDocuments(collection.getSelfLink());
console.log(data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
// Query documents and take 1st item.
var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
    collection.getSelfLink(),
    'SELECT * FROM root r',
function (err, feed, options) {
    if (err) throw err;

    // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
    // else take 1st element from feed
    if (!feed || !feed.length) {
        var response = getContext().getResponse();
        response.setBody('no docs found');
    }
    else {
        var response = getContext().getResponse();
        var body = { prefix: prefix, feed: feed[0] };
        response.setBody(JSON.stringify(body));
    }
});

if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

After all, this is just the sample query that the portal generates. The only issue is that it does not return any results.

- The collection has 7000 documents
- It is partitioned by a prop type `/EmailTypeId`
- When I execute the query I am submitting partition value of `5` (which is the partition value for all current records)
- I'm console.logging a call to `collection.readDocuments` which should return all docs but it just returns the value `true`

## I'm trying to return all records so I can aggregate by id and count. How can I get this query to actually return data?

**Here is a sample screen shot of one of the doc schemas in the collection**
[image]
**Here is the input form for supplying the partition value**
[image]

### Update

I created a new collection as a control. This collection has no partition key and it seems the same query returns results in that collection. Therefor the issue has to be in the 2nd screen shot I provided. Perhaps I am providing the partition key incorrectly.

Comment: I feel your pain... shouldn't be this difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to limit your response size since there is a limit coming from cosmo. I added something like this in my sproc to alleviate this:

```
if (responseSize + queryPageSize < 1024 * 1024) {
      // Append query results to nodesBatch.
      nodesBatch = nodesBatch.concat(documentsRead);

      // Keep track of the response size.
      responseSize += queryPageSize;

      if (responseOptions.continuation) {
        // If there is a continuation token... Run the query again to get the next page of results
        lastContinuationToken = responseOptions.continuation;
        getNodes(responseOptions.continuation);
      } else {
        // If there is no continutation token, we are done. Return the response.
        response.setBody({
          "message": "Query completed succesfully.",
          "queryResponse": nodesBatch
        });
      }
    } else {
      // If the response size limit reached; run the script again with the lastContinuationToken as a script parameter.
      response.setBody({
        "message": "Response size limit reached.",
        "lastContinuationToken": lastContinuationToken,
        "queryResponse": nodesBatch
      });
    }
  });
```

Let me know how this works for you.

Also, check your collection name and use that instead of `root`

Comment: Just read on azure docs that input parameters in the portal are sent as strings. This may be the issue. Perhaps the input partition key value is sent as a string as well but my partition key is an int.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is not complete. I read this about 10 times and still don't understand what I should do exactly :) I only learned there is some limit and I should handle it but how - it's a big question mark.